# What is response in page.on function in apify?

Tags: puppeteer, apify

what is `response` in the `page.on` function?

In "https://github.com/vdrmota/actor-twitter-scraper/blob/master/src/scraper.js" example on line 17 you check that the `response.url` includes `"/timeline/profile/"`.

The `page.url()` is `https://twitter.com/${handle}/with_replies`. So why check on line 17 that the URL includes `"/timeline/profile/"`?

Answer (score 0):

`page.on('response', handler)` calls the handler function every time the page receives a response to one of its requests. It can be the main document, but also various CSS files, images, scripts and so on. Therefore, the URL check is there to filter out only the relevant responses.

See Puppeteer docs for more info: https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&show=api-event-response